# finding file_id of a group media message in telegram by telebot library

Tags: bots, telegram, message, group, telebot

In my bot, I received a forwarded media group message which contains 3 different photos. Now I want to catch all these 3 photos and send them again to another `chat_id`. However, all values in `message.photo.file_id` are representing the same photo in various resolutions and when I store this `file_id` in a list to use it in `media` section of `bot.send_media_group`, it makes a group of the same photo.

My question is, how can I find those three picture unique `file_id` to store in my list and use it in `media` section of `bot.send_media_group`

my code is below:

```
    for i in message.photo:
                    print(i.file_id)
                    list_file_id.append(i.file_id)
                print(message)
                print(list_file_id)

    bot.send_media_group(channelData.chat_ID, media = [InputMediaPhoto(media = i) for i in list_file_id], caption= "hellow")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the wrong parameter, but it's what I define a **false friend**.

The attribute *photo* into the Message Telegram object represents all of the available **sizes** related to the picture into the message itself ([documentation here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#photosize)).

It's a false friend because as you tried so far, you're getting the different picture sizes instead of the *file_id* which could be found into the other message's object attributes.

Comment: yes, I figured it out after some trying. However, now I don't know how to store file_id for a group picture message. Could you please help me?

Comment: This is another point Ali, this question has to be closed if my answer is considered as valid.